# Одно модальное окно с разным содержимым на php

Tags: javascript, php, php7

Всем привет, такой вопрос:
-Каким образом я могу сделать модальное окно с разным содержимым внутри?
-Наполнения модального окна зависит от того на какую кнопку я нажимаю.
-Нужно это реализовать на php.
Спасибо)

Comment: ajax'ом делать запрос на php,  с него отдавать те данные которые вам нужны и вставлять в модальное окно

Comment: вы определитесь, что значит разное содержимое. 1) это в принципе разные окна 2) одно окно с разными данными. Далее определитесь, достаточно ли вам в момент нажатия данных на странице, чтобы сформировать это окно, или надо их запрашивать на сервере. Потом решите, имеет ли смысл рендерить весь контент на стороне сервера, либо достаточно выдать только данные, и подставить на клиенте.

Comment: @teran "это в принципе разные окна"
- Окно должно быть одно, а данные должны подгружаться в зависимости от того на какую кнопку я нажимаю.
- Достаточно выдать только данные и подставить их на клиенте.

Comment: а что вы планируете использовать для решения вашей задачи на стороне клиента(js библиотека или нативный код)? почему вам нужен php? вы хотите тянуть контент для окон из БД или какая вообще задумка?

Comment: @МаксМаксимус нет, из бд нечего тянуть не нужно.
Нужно просто реализовать модалку с контентом контентом подгружаемым в зависимости от нажатой кнопки.
Сейчас есть просто 3 модалки с раздным контентом. Нужно сделать так что бы модалка была одна и в ней менялся контент.